# numpy.ndenumerate to return indices in Fortran order?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator, iteration

When using `numpy.ndenumerate` the indices are returned following for a `C-contiguous` array order, for example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[11, 12],
              [21, 22],
              [31, 32]])

for (i,j),v in np.ndenumerate(a):
    print i, j, v
```

No mather if the `order` in `a` is `'F'` or `'C'`, this gives:

```
0 0 11
0 1 12
1 0 21
1 1 22
2 0 31
2 1 32
```

Is there any built-in iterator in `numpy` like `ndenumerate` to give this (following the array `order='F'`):

```
0 0 11
1 0 21
2 0 31
0 1 12
1 1 22
2 1 32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with [`np.nditer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html) as follows:

```
it = np.nditer(a, flags=['multi_index'], order='F')
while not it.finished:
    print it.multi_index, it[0]
    it.iternext()
```

`np.nditer` is a very powerful beast that exposes some of the internal C iterator in Python, take a look at [*Iterating Over Arrays*](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html) in the docs.

Comment: Oops! Just added `it.iternext()` inside the loop to make the iteration advance...

Comment: I think `for item in it` also works. I'm not clear why the docs chose this peculiar way to advance the iterator. Do you?

Comment: Not a clue. I don't think I had ever tried to use `nditer` in Python until today...

Answer (score 4):

Just taking a transpose would give you what you want:

```
a = np.array([[11, 12],
              [21, 22],
              [31, 32]])

for (i,j),v in np.ndenumerate(a.T):
    print j, i, v
```

Result:

```
0 0 11
1 0 21
2 0 31
0 1 12
1 1 22
2 1 32
```

Comment: Yes, this is definitely better :)

Comment: @Akavall Great catch!